# Meaning of 舌の根の乾かぬうち

Tags: phrases

I think I got it, but I would like to confirm just to check if it is correct or if I am missing some subtlety that happens when I translate. What is the meaning of 「舌｛した｝の根｛ね｝の乾｛かわ｝かぬ内{うち}に」?

From both the context and some search online, it seems to be something along the lines "I just said it" or "did I not just say it before this". The next sentence after this phrase was「私は嘘{うそ}は言わないんだ」, which translates to "Didn't I just say that I never lie" and seems to flow just fine (?).

Comment: why "supposedly"? you don't have the full text?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky edited. It is followed by that sentence, not just supposedly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 「舌{した}の根{ね}の乾{かわ}かぬ内{うち}に」
>
> From both the context and some search online, it seems to be something along the lines "I just said it" or "did I not just say it before this".

Kind of related but not quite (unless you could provide enough context that makes you think that way.)

It is an idiomatic expression used to accuse a person of (unexpectedly) making a contradictory/contrasting/highly different comment ***immediately*** after making an original comment.  It is often used in the sentence pattern:

「[Person] は A と言い/言ったのに、舌の根の乾かぬ内に B と言った。」

The closest English expression I could think of would be:

> "(to say two things) ***in the same breath***".

Comment: +1 for very clear explanation on the "immediate" part. It is exactly how it would fit, now that I read it.